"When you raise up the lamps, to the face of the menorah, light 7 lamps"?
B"H
In Parshas bahalosecha it says
"When you raise up the lamps, to the face of the menorah, light 7 lamps"
Why does it first mention "raising up the lamps", without mentioning the number of lamps, but then it concludes "... Light 7 lamps".
Why mention the number of lamps only at the end and not at the beginning, and why split up the idea into two different sections?
A slightly different, but related, question is why does it say "to the face of the menorah, light 7 lamps", if the entire menorah had 7 lamps total, and the "face of the menorah" is the middle lamp, so really only 6 candles are lit "towards" it.
Is there some kind of deeper significance for why it mentions "7" lamps, and specifically at the end of the verse?
